# Dashboard Designer in SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, dashboard-designer-2013

I am trying to open Dashboard Designer in my SharePoint Server 2013.But the problem is whenever I try to create a DashBoard Designer  a file name desinger.application gets downloaded and the Dashboard Designer doesnot show up.

**Error**
[image]

How to fix it?

**Updated Error**

[image]

I have excel services running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also same problem.

Open your site in **Internet Explorer** and then click on "Dashboard Designer". It will open.
*NOTE: Try on machine where you SharePoint server is installed.*

Comment: I did that But Now I am getting authentication error.Please see my updated Question.

Comment: May be Windows/IE is not remembering your credentials to pass them to the application. So you need to check the “Save password” or “Remember my Credentials” in browser. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct whenever I see that type of error is that you don't have the site set as trusted.  Adding the site to the 'Intranet' zone will allow for automatic logins, and usually handle client applications like Dashboard designer also.